# root password found changed. Did someone break into my server?

Tags: centos, security, centos6

This morning I found myself unable to log into the root account on one of my (CentOS 6) servers. I booted into single user mode and reset the root password. Everything seems to be working normally now.

I have a number of monitoring metrics that watch behavior on this server and have seen no evidence of nefarious activity. However, I am not sure I can trust the security of this server without doing a full OS reinstall.

- What steps can I take to diagnose the cause of this?
- In theory someone may have had root access to my machine. Is there any way I can rule this possibility out?

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. As always; nuke it from orbit, reset your root passwords, don't let root login via SSH.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am not sure how I missed that one while searching for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could just forget the password, it happened to me. :-)

If your server was compromised, then you can't trust data or code stored on it. Maybe you have some external logging facilities, like:

- a remote syslog server,
- a firewall appliance which logs connections,
- or even just a managed switch which logs connections?

I would not hesitate to reinstall this machine. In the meanwhile try configuring a remote logging place; you can use one of your servers for that.
I recommend some reading about configuration possibilities (like protocols available); this seems like a good compendium of knowledge:

https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/managing-linux-logs/